# Plot ramp function

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot a ramp function in MATLAB. 
I have the following function for my ramp:

```
function [ y ] = ramp(x)
    y=zeros(size(x));
    y(x>=0)=linspace(0,x(end),length(x(x>=0)))
end
```

But, I want it to have a similiar effect as my step function

```
syms x
ezplot(5*heaviside(x-1), [-10, 10])
```

When I use this code:

```
 syms x
 ezplot(5*ramp(x-1), [-10, 10])
```

When I do (x-1) it seems to throw an error that it is impossible, may I ask for some modificaitons?:

```
Cannot prove '0 <= x - 1' literally. To test the statement mathematically,
use isAlways.
```

Comment: No need for `ezplot`, just use `plot`.

Answer (score 1):

Your step function plot works with a function of symbolic variable x. But `ramp`, the way you have written it, is a function that expects numerical input (a vector of x-values). This is why your attempt to pass a symbolic x to it fails. Here is a correct way to plot this function:

```
x = linspace(-10,10,100);
plot(x, 5*ramp(x-1))
```

Alternatively, you can rewrite `ramp` as a function of a symbolic variable:

```
function  y  = symbramp(x)
    y = (x+abs(x))/2;
end
```

and plot it as you did with Heaviside:

```
syms x
ezplot(5*symbramp(x-1), [-10,10])
```